# VF Page - Landing page - Building Tables

Tags: dynamic-visualforce

I am creating a VF page that will serve as a "Landing" page when Partners using our Portal, click a link for Sales Training. The Page is fairly straight forward to create, however I'm not sure how to make it "function" like this...
1. The Landing Page will have a "section" with two web links. One foe Sales Training and one for Sales Engeneering Training. If a partner clicks the Sales Training link, a table of web links would pop up. If the partner clicks the Sales Eng. link, then two (2) tables need to pop up. The one with the links to the sales traininig vidoes, and a 2nd tabel with links to Engineering videos.
I have created a Custom Object in SFDC so Marketing and Training can add or delete the links for the training videos that will populate the table. I just do not know how to write the APEX code to make the tables pop up with the data (weblinks) in them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following as a sample page to get an idea about the functionality you want to achieve. You can use this as a support/reference and enhance it further to meet your requirements.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false">

    <style>     
        h3 {
        color: black;
        }
        .texter {
        display:none;
        padding:10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .Section {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding-left:30px;
        padding-right:30px;
        }
        .Topic {
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: pointer;
        }

        @media print {.texter {display:block;}}

    </style>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">       
        function openAndClose(id) 
        {
            if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "block") 
            {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none" }
            else {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block" } 
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <apex:form >
        <div >
            <h3> Landing Page </h3>
        </div>  
        <div Class="Section">          
            <br/>
            <b > Partner Portal Landing page </b> 
            <br/><br/>
            <li><u onClick="openAndClose('Training')" style="cursor:pointer">Sales Training</u></li>
            <div id="Training" class="texter">
                <!-- Since you have created a custom object to add/remove links, you can create a controller and use the iteration component apex:repeat tag to display all the links-->
                <table><tr><td><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a></td></tr></table>
            </div>
            <li><u onClick="openAndClose('Engineering')" style="cursor:pointer">Sales Engineering</u></li>
            <div id="Engineering" class="texter">
                <!-- Since you have created a custom object to add/remove links, you can create a controller and use the iteration component apex:repeat tag to display all the links-->
                <table><tr><td><a href="https://www.Yahoo.com/" target="_blank">Yahoo</a></td></tr></table>
            </div>
            <br/><br/>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code I came up with to resolve this issue.
I created a Custom Object so I could enter in all the Training courses and then display them on a VF page.

Hi {!$User.FirstName}!

```
   <apex:pageBlock >
          Welcome to Guidance Software's Sales Training and Certification Course

          <p>We are pleased to launch the first phase of our new sales-based curriculum designed exclusively for our channel partner community. By completing both the Sales Certification and Technical/Pre-Sales Certification modules, partners will be moved up to the “Certified Partner” tier of the Guidance Global Partner Program, and with that comes many additional benefits, resources and additional discounts.</p>

          <p>Below is the "link" for our Sales Training and Certification Program.</p>

          <p>This program is designed as a series of videos (ranging from 2-25 minutes each) on a variety of topics and solutions.</p>

          <p>Once you are ready to take the Certification Exam, click on the "Exam Request" link below to email ChannelHotline@guidancesoftware.com with a request for Exam Access.</p>

  </apex:pageBlock>
```

```
     <p><apex:outputLink value="https://gsiprod--sfdcadmin--c.cs8.visual.force.com/apex/Sales_Certification_Courses">Sales Training and Certification Courses</apex:outputLink></p>
     <p><apex:outputLink value="https://gsiprod--sfdcadmin--c.cs8.visual.force.com/apex/Engineering_Certification_Courses">Engineering Training and Certification Courses</apex:outputLink></p>
     <p><apex:outputLink value="https://gsiprod--sfdcadmin--c.cs8.visual.force.com/apex/Sales_Certification_Courses">All Courses</apex:outputLink></p>

  </apex:pageBlock>
```